# change the color of right taskbar in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I just upgraded my windows to 8.1 ,I wanted to change the color of right task bar but I can not find where ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all press the windows button then after swipe right your mouse click on setting then after that click on personalize ,so you can change the back ground color.that's it